# Add parameter to an AWS CloudFormation / CodePipeline stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I created an application from the AWS Console, in Lambda:

[image]

That app uses sam, cloud formation, code pipeline (deploying automatically on each push to Github), etc. It comes with a parameter defined in `template.yml`:

```yaml
Parameters:
  AppId:
    Type: String
```

but now I added a few more:

```yaml
Parameters:
  AppId:
    Type: String
  CognitoUserPoolName:
    Type: String
  CognitoUserPoolClientName:
    Type: String
```

Where in AWS should I define the values for those?

Note: I don't deploy by running `sam deploy`, Code Pipeline deploys automatically for me. That's how that "Serverless API backend" template works out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### SAM

You set [Parameter Overrides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html) in the `sam deploy` command or in [samconfig.toml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html) locally.

```sh
# The `--parameter-overrides` option is a string of key-value pairs corresponding to the parameters in your SAM template.
sam deploy --parameter-overrides 'AppId=MyReallySuperApp,CognitoUserPoolName=AppPool' ...etc
```

##### CodePipeline

CodePipeline,pipeline deploy stages [also accept parameter overrides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-parameter-override-functions.html), in the console or with the [update-pipeline](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/codepipeline/update-pipeline.html) api command.  You can create additional deploy stages for each combination of a stack's parameter values you wish to deploy.

However you provide them, parameter values are set at deploy-time.  You can view a deployed stack's parameter values in the CloudFormation console.

BTW, the option is called Parameter *Overrides* because you can set a default template value for each Parameter.

```yaml
Parameters:
  AppId:
    Type: String
    Default: MySuperApp
```

Comment: Doesn't `sam deploy` actually deploys the app? Is that a one time thing so that the parameter is recorded? Will that deploy behave the same as the code pipeline that deploys from github automatically?

Comment: I edited the answer to explain how template parameters work with CodePipeline.

Comment: Thank you. I read that document, but I still can't figure out. All of those snippets look like they belong in files which weren't created for my project. And when it comes to updating them in the console, where?

Comment: The command line API seems to point to having a file that defines the code pipeline, that you modify and then re-apply. But the Lambda application template doesn't create that file, it just magically spawns the pipeline.

Comment: in the console:  [CodePipeline] > [`Pipeline/Pipelines/Pipeline` in sidebar] > [select pipeline] > [`Edit` button] > [find deploy stage - `Edit stage` button] > [`StackName.Prepare` Action "pencil" icon] > [Advanced] > [`Parameter overrides`]